# Show only year in DatePicker

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, datepicker, calendar

I am using custom class for datepicker for multiple fragment. Its working fine but in one fragment i want to show only year in Dialog Fragment via Date Picker.

Custom DatePicker Class

```
public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    public static final String TAG="###Date Selector###";
    String name;
    String To,From;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG,"ON CREATE CALLING ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(TAG,"ON START CALLING ");
        Log.d(TAG,"Fragment Is Calling By "+name+" "+To+" "+From);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG,"On Create Dialog Calling");
        name=getArguments().getString("Calling");
        To=getArguments().getString("To");
        From=getArguments().getString("From");
        if (name.equals("###EDIT PROFILE###")) {
            int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
        } else if (name.equals("====Add PPL====")) {
            int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),this,yy,mm,00);

        }
        return null;
    }


    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
        populateSetDate(yy, mm+1, dd);
    }
    public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        TextView dob=null;
        if (name.equals("###EDIT PROFILE###")){
            dob= (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.edit_profile_dobTextView);
            Log.d(TAG,"Calling Fragment is Edit Profile");
        }
        else if (name.equals("====Add PPL====")){
            Log.d(TAG,"Calling Fragment is ADD PPL");
            if (To!=null && !To.equals("")){
                dob=(TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ppl_To_passing_year);
                Log.d(TAG,"Calling Fragment is ADD PPL and inside TO");
            }
            else if (From!=null && !From.equals("")){
                dob=(TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ppl_From_passing_year);
                Log.d(TAG,"Calling Fragment is ADD PPL and inside From");
            }

        }

        String nameOfMonth=new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[month-1];
        dob.setText(day+" "+nameOfMonth+" "+year);
    }

}
```

I want to show only year in dialog and sometimes month and year. I am bound to edit this class only to get Year or Month and Year.

Thanks

Comment: use number picker than

Comment: Can't we do with date picker (With this code)

Comment: you can't do that in date picker

Comment: It's hard to make something (the date picker) do something that it's not designed for, espcially if something that is designed to do exactly that thing (number picker) exists.

Comment: @KarlRichter so can we show only month and year thn?

Comment: You can use a wheel instead of datepicker. Because it is a **Date**picker!